# Is it a good idea to have a Pyromancer and Sorcerer combination?

Tags: dark-souls

Basically I'm asking if it is a good idea to have a Pyromancer and Sorcerer build. I've already started a Sorcerer with 45 int and 45 dex and I want to know if I've messed up the possibility. My attunment is 19 so I have a decent amount of slots available for a good mix and match of the two classes.

Comment: I like to use a talisman as my right hand second, with Sunlight Spear, Homeward and Heal, and then my left hand second, a pyromancy with whatever.

Comment: Well, if you're playing Dark Souls 1, then there is literally no reason to *not* be a Pyromancer, because it is not based on any stats and doesn't up your SL. All you need to do is dump souls into the pyromancy flame. So yes, it is a good idea to have pyromancy on literally every character you make.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I actually used that build and finished the game (without the DLC, I never got around to buying the DLC)

Pyromancer has this nifty spell called Poison (and its upgrade Toxic) Mist, it'll deal a lot of damage for basically doing nothing and helps to save that awesome Soul Spear for those that really warrant it.

It also has Warmth to help you heal, and Lingering Flame to set traps against melee enemies. Pyromancy is basically useless against long ranged enemies but quite good in close range, something that sorcery could use some help with. Also, Flame Swathe, that sh** be badass yo.

But just like other magic, the good spells take up quite a few slots. Study your own playstyle and decide which spells to take to battle.

I personally used Flame Swathe, Lingering Flame, Fire Whip, Fireball and Toxic Mist for Pyromancy, and brought Soul Spear plus Heavy Soul Arrow for the Sorcery part.